# Find class inside class with jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to do something like the following in jQuery

`$('.container').siblings('.outerClass > .innerClass')`

where I'm looking for:

```
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="outerClass">
    <div class="innerClass">
        find me!
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't get the syntax right.

Comment: `.innerClass` is not sibling to the `.container` that is why it fails .. @Felix Kling's answer should cover you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And another one (but this should work) (*assuming you want to get the element with class `innerClass`*):

```
$('.container').siblings('.outerClass').children('.innerClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem ommitting the container selector, and just using

```
$('.outerClass > .innerClass')
```

or perhaps (if you don't want to require the inner div to be a *direct* child)

```
$('.outerClass .innerClass')
```

Comment: yeah I need the container siblings part unfortunately. I tried both of those and I don't think it worked (unless I've made a mistake calculating the html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this to directly select the required elements

```
$(".outerClass").children(".innerClass").click(function() {
//Do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container').siblings('.outerClass:has(> .innerClass)')
```

To explain why; `.outerClass > .innerClass` is a selector that selects an element with class innerClass, not the outerClass. To select an element that has something specific in it, you use the `:has` selector, which takes a selector as an argument.